# サイトの和訳で役立つ参考資料まとめ

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, 翻訳

日本語訳で不自然だと思う箇所があるのですが、ぴったりな言葉が出てきません。参考になるサイトはありませんか？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 2):

### オンライン辞書

- [Weblio類語辞典](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/)
- [翻訳訳語辞典](https://www.dictjuggler.net/yakugo/) — 実際に出版された和訳書から訳語の事例を検索

### 似た機能をもつ他のサイト

ネイティブサイト

- [Qiita](https://qiita.com/) — ユーザー投稿 + コメント + 編集機能
- [teratail](https://teratail.com/about) — エンジニア向けQ&Aサイト :o
- [Zenn](https://zenn.dev/about) — エンジニア向けの情報共有コミュニティ

和訳されたサイト

- [スラド](https://srad.jp/faq/) — モデレーション